# Display page inside div from submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to create a page with a simple input form, use that to create the URL required and display the resulting page in a div all in one go. When I sent the user directly to the created URL from clicking submit that worked perfectly, but I can't seem to get it to do anything with the following code:

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<form id="theForm">
    <input id='subj'/>
    <input type='submit'/>
</form>

<script>
    var theForm = document.getElementById('theForm');
    var theInput = document.getElementById('subj');
    var show;

    theForm.onsubmit = function(e){
        show = "www.someurl.com/" + encodeURIComponent(theInput.value);
        return show;
        $('#display').load(show);
    }
</script>

<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: You're exiting the submit handler before calling `load()`. The `return` statement should be the last thing in the function block. Also you have an odd mix of JS and jQuery. I would suggest using one or the other.

Comment: And submiting the form reload the page, you need to prevent this behaviour

Comment: you can use AJAX call instead of submit button

Comment: @rory I moved the return statement to the end of the function and now it doesn't seem to do anything at all when I hit submit, before it was at least accepting what I typed. Now it doesn't clear the form out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed three things and got the code to work:
 1. Changed the div to an iFrame
 2. Added an "action" attribute to the form and set it to "#" so that the program doesn't exit the webpage upon clicking the form.
 3. Removed the "encodeURIComponent" command from the code, because it didn't work with it..

This is my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form id="theForm" action="#">
    <input id='subj'/>
    <input type='submit'/>
</form>

<iframe id="display"></iframe>

<script>
    var theForm = document.getElementById('theForm');
    var theInput = document.getElementById('subj');
    var show;

    theForm.onsubmit = function(e){
        var show = "http://someUrl.com/" + (theInput.value);
        console.log(show);
        document.getElementById("display").src= show;
    }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```